# How did Barbara Gordon (Oracle) become disabled?

Tags: dc, batman, batgirl

Is there any record on the information about how Barbara Gordon or the Batgirl became disabled?

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64871/was-there-any-canon-description-of-the-extent-of-barbara-gordons-paralysis/64882#64882

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [Wikia](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Barbara_Gordon_%28New_Earth%29#The_Killing_Joke):

> As the years went on, however, Barbara found her role as Batgirl less and less fulfilling, and she eventually more or less retired.
>
> That's when the Joker showed up at her house, shooting and paralyzing her and when he kidnapped her [father]<sup>1</sup>. Batman rescued Jim Gordon, but 19-year-old Barbara Gordon's career as a crime fighter was over. She spent a month in a deep depression.

This happened in 1988 "Batman: [The Killing Joke](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman:_The_Killing_Joke)"

Also, more details are on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbara_Gordon):

> Following the editorial retirement of her Batgirl persona in Barbara Kesel's Batgirl Special #1, Alan Moore's graphic novel Batman: The Killing Joke depicts the Joker shooting her through the spinal cord in her civilian identity, resulting in paraplegia.
>
> In subsequent stories, editor Kim Yale and writer John Ostrander establish the character as a computer expert and information broker known as Oracle.

---

<sup>1</sup> The Wikia incorrectly identifies Jim Gordon as Barbara's uncle.

Answer (score 3):

As an answer to the question posed in the title:

> The character made her first comic book appearance as Oracle in
>   **Suicide Squad #23**, anonymously offering her services to the
>   government's Task Force X. In the following two years, Oracle
>   … made guest appearances in various DC
>   titles until her identity was revealed to be Barbara Gordon in **Suicide
>   Squad #38** (1990). She officially becomes a member of the Squad in
>   issue #48, following an invitation from Amanda Waller.